# How to parse Json with HTML inside in swift

Tags: html, ios, json, swift

I'm responding data with HTML page inside. 
I'm converting response data to a string and have a string like:

```
{
  "Result": {
    "NewsId": 10,
    "Body": "<p><span style=\"font-family: Verdana, 'Geneva CY', Helvetica, 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12.8000001907349px;line-height: 20.4799995422363px;\">Some body text</span</p>",
    "PublishDate": null,
    "Title": null,
    "HashTags": [
    ],
    "Attachments": [
    ]
  },
  "Status": 200,
  "Error": null
}
```

Now I want to parse it into Array with keys;

But my code crushes:

```
let jsonData = responseString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
var boardsDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! Array<NSDictionary>
```

Error

```
error = domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840
```

Now, how can I parse my JSON with HTML inside it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decieded to resolve this problem in other way.
I have a string with HTML and tags with "Result", "Body" etc.

I'm taking HTML string as substring between two tags `"Body":` and `"PublishDate"` I know, that this resolution looks a little bit dummy, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your JSON is not valid - you need to escape the double-quotes (") properly. Please have a look at the JSON standard: http://json.org